Why did they opt for the message "most recent call last"?
If "most recent call last" means the most recent call is at the end of the stack, so what? What does this imply? How is this piece of information useful for me?

Back in the day, A C debugger would typically show the current stack frame and there would be a command to walk back from there. Most recent call first. In my opinion It's the more natural way to display the information so the python note is appreciated.

It just ensures you're reading the traceback in the correct order. Different programming languages show call stack traces in a different order. How would you interpret this stack trace?
foo()
bar()
baz()

Did baz call bar which called foo and you're looking at "the top" of the stack? Or did foo call bar which called baz? Depends on the language and its convention.
"Most recent call last" clarifies that it's the latter; foo came first, then bar, then baz.
